# What happens if you complete a StickerBook during the Steam Summer Sale?

Tags: steam

I guess the title is pretty self explanatory. *What is the benefit in collecting these stickers* - do you receive anything(like when crafting a badge from the trading cards) when you collect all stickers from a sticker book?

Thanks

Comment: One reward is an option to feature a page in your Steam profile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the stickers page on the Steam store:

> Once you've applied all of the stickers that correspond to a specific page, that page will permanently unlock on your account.
>
> For all of your unlocked pages, you'll be able to customize them any way you want with your extra stickers.

Additionally, you'll be able to feature unlocked sticker pages on your profile.

After completing the entire sticker book, you will also receive the "Sticker Completionist" badge.

Comment: What happens if you continue to complete quests after completing all the sticker pages?

Comment: @Abion47 Nothing.